# Combining two objects but if first object already has a property ignore the property in second object

Tags: javascript, object

Given two objects, "extend" adds properties from the 2nd object to the 1st object.

Notes:

- Add any keys that are not in the 1st object.
- If the 1st object already has a given key, ignore it (do not overwrite the property value).
- Do not modify the 2nd object at all.

  ```
  var obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  };
  var obj2 = {
    b: 4,
    c: 3
  };

  extend(obj1, obj2);

  console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  ```

I was able to get this far :

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var key in obj2) {
    obj1[key] = obj2[key]; 
  }
 return obj1;
}
```

which logged:

```
{a: 1, b: 4, c: 3}
```

I've been cracking my skull trying to figure this out for the passed two days or so. Tried googling and everything. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i edited the question to show how far i've gotten. I dont know how to omit the b:4 in the second object if first object already has a key named b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just need to iterate through each key on the 2nd object and see if the first object has that key or not.

The iteration can be done using a [`for..in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), as you know. The part your're missing is how to check if an object already has a given property. That's what [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is for.

```js
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  // Iterate over every (enumerable) key in obj2
  for (var key in obj2) {
    // If obj1 does not have a key by this name,
    // add it to obj1
    if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
  }
}

var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

extend(obj1, obj2);
console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comment: yes that worked! I think i remembered trying this earlier too but i typed 

if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty[key]) < --- the bracket really screwed me up LOL